# read_only field in django rest serializer with unique_together contraint

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I wanted to make email field unique in default django User model. So i made it `unique_together=[('email',)]` . Now in serializer I want it to be a read_only field. 
But Django Rest Framework 3.0 docs says:

> There is a special-case where a read-only field is part of a
>   unique_together constraint at the model level. In this case the field
>   is required by the serializer class in order to validate the
>   constraint, but should also not be editable by the user.
>
> The right way to deal with this is to specify the field explicitly on
>   the serializer, providing both the read_only=True and default=…
>   keyword arguments.
>
> > One example of this is a read-only relation to the currently
> >     authenticated User which is unique_together with another identifier.
> >     In this case you would declare the user field like so:
>
> user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True,
>   default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

serializers.CurrentUserDefault() represents the current user.I want to set default as user's email . Isn't `serializers.CurrentUserDefault()` equivalent to `request.user` . `serializers.CurrentUserDefault().email` is giving error `'CurrentUserDefault' object has no attribute 'email'` How to set email default as user's email ?

Comment: Can you solve this issue? or Do you find any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is what the documentation of `CurrentUserDefault` says:

> A default class that can be used to represent the current user. In
>   order to use this, the 'request' must have been provided as part of
>   the context dictionary when instantiating the serializer.

You can either do that or you can provide the email id passed in the `context data` in your `views`. Override the function `get_serializer_context`

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    context = super(YourClass, self).get_serializer_context()
    context['email'] = request.user.email

    return context
```

in your `views`. Your `view` should be extended from `GenericAPIView` at some level of inheritance. Now in your `serializer`, override your `__init__` and get your email data.

```
def __init__(self, instance = None,  data = serializers.empty, *args, **kwargs):
    self.email = kwargs['context']['email']
```

Now you can use that in your serializer.

Comment: `Your view should be extended from GenericAPIView` Why ? , I am using function based view and passing context like `serializer = UserProfileSerializer(request.user, data=request.data,context={'request': request})`

Comment: Yes that would also do and get your context in kwargs

Comment: Tried to use this in serializer  `def __init__(self, instance = None,data = serializers.empty, *args, **kwargs):
        self.email = kwargs['context']['request'].user.email` . I am getting Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.

Comment: Call super also... You are overriding the  serializer __init__ function

Comment: Tried this `def __init__(self,instance = None,data=serializers.empty,*args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.email=kwargs['context']['request'].user.email` Its not returning data.

Answer (score 2):

Please check solution 2 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317628/unique-together-of-two-field-messes-with-read-only-fields/56061820#56061820)

The code can be:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'read_only': True},
        }


    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Override create to provide a email via request.user by default."""
        if 'email' not in validated_data:
            validated_data['email'] = self.context['request'].user.email

        return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

hope it help :)