# Django REST Framework CurrentUserDefault() with serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.7

I have been trying for a while now to add an 'owner' field to my models. I have looked at other questions but I still have had no luck. Ideally when a new note is created, the current user will be set in the owner field and won't be changeable.

Below is my model, serializer, and view for a Note as far as I have gotten. I'm guessing the CurrentUserDefault() function needs additional context but I can't set it properly.

**views.py**

```
class NoteListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (DjangoModelPermissions,)
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = serializers.NoteSummarySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Note.objects.all()
        # general search
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(content__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
        # title search
        query = self.request.GET.get('title')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=query)
        # content search
        query = self.request.GET.get('content')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(content__icontains=query)
        return qs
```

**serializers.py**

```
class NoteSummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'title',
            'containerId',
            'created',
            'updated',
            'owner',
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class Base(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['title', '-updated']


class Note(Base):
    containerId = models.ForeignKey(Folder, related_name='notes', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'marknote_notes'
```

When I try to post a new note, I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /marknote/note
NOT NULL constraint failed: marknote_notes.owner_id

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/marknote/note
Django Version: 2.1
Python Executable: /Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path: ['/Users/sheldonwoodward/Developer/projects/marknote', '/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7', '/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time: Tue, 21 Aug 2018 02:57:59 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'marknote']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: marknote_notes.owner_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
  244.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  21.         self.perform_create(serializer)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in perform_create
  26.         serializer.save()

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in create
  940.             instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  413.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  717.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  747.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  830.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  868.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1133.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1285.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /marknote/note
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: marknote_notes.owner_id
Request information:
USER: sheldonwoodward

GET: No GET data

POST:
title = 'Test 1'
content = 'Test 1'

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES: No cookie data

META:
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Ub5WC3uGKI/Render'
CLICOLOR = '1'
COLORFGBG = '15;0'
COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
CONTENT_LENGTH = '278'
CONTENT_TYPE = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------010663819168948174069971'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'django_server.settings'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = 'CGI/1.1'
HOME = '/Users/sheldonwoodward'
HTTP_ACCEPT = '*/*'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip, deflate'
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = 'Token f093f174c4e5df0e1ea2c0ed96b06e15ff210070'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = 'no-cache'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
HTTP_HOST = 'localhost:8000'
HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN = '1a299d28-3fe5-4b44-afb0-bfaf812f450f'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'PostmanRuntime/7.2.0'
ITERM_PROFILE = 'Sheldon'
ITERM_SESSION_ID = 'w1t0p0:DEBAC83E-F158-4352-B9F7-A2E992591FAC'
LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LOGNAME = 'sheldonwoodward'
LSCOLORS = 'GxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx'
PATH = '/Users/sheldonwoodward/.local/share/virtualenvs/marknote-1Se4K7YM/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.7.1/libexec/tools:/Applications/MAMP PRO/Library/bin/:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sheldonwoodward/.javacc-6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:/Users/sheldonwoodward/.composer/vendor/bin'
PATH_INFO = '/marknote/note'
PIP_PYTHON_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.7.1/libexec/bin/python3.7'
PWD = '/Users/sheldonwoodward/Developer/projects/marknote'
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE = '1'
QUERY_STRING = ''
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST = ''
REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'
RUN_MAIN = 'true'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_NAME = '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
SERVER_PORT = '8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'WSGIServer/0.2'
SHELL = '/bin/bash'
SHLVL = '1'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.slrqyEZVoL/Listeners'
TERM = 'xterm-256color'
TERM_PROGRAM = 'iTerm.app'
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '3.1.6'
TERM_SESSION_ID = 'w1t0p0:DEBAC83E-F158-4352-B9F7-A2E992591FAC'
TMPDIR = '/var/folders/kh/c1hbp5r97b9fbwqny9rr7cym0000gp/T/'
TZ = 'UTC'
USER = 'sheldonwoodward'
XPC_FLAGS = '0x0'
XPC_SERVICE_NAME = '0'
_ = '/usr/local/bin/pipenv'
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F6:0x0:0x0'
wsgi.errors = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
wsgi.input = <_io.BufferedReader name=5>
wsgi.multiprocess = False
wsgi.multithread = True
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = '(1, 0)'

Settings:
Using settings module django_server.settings
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}
ADMINS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
APPEND_SLASH = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = '********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
BASE_DIR = '/Users/sheldonwoodward/Developer/projects/marknote'
CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = '********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = 31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = []
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': '/Users/sheldonwoodward/Developer/projects/marknote/db.sqlite3', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 1000
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = []
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE = '********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
FIXTURE_DIRS = []
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'rest_framework', 'rest_framework.authtoken', 'marknote']
INTERNAL_IPS = []
LANGUAGES = [('af', 'Afrikaans'), ('ar', 'Arabic'), ('ast', 'Asturian'), ('az', 'Azerbaijani'), ('bg', 'Bulgarian'), ('be', 'Belarusian'), ('bn', 'Bengali'), ('br', 'Breton'), ('bs', 'Bosnian'), ('ca', 'Catalan'), ('cs', 'Czech'), ('cy', 'Welsh'), ('da', 'Danish'), ('de', 'German'), ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'), ('el', 'Greek'), ('en', 'English'), ('en-au', 'Australian English'), ('en-gb', 'British English'), ('eo', 'Esperanto'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'), ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'), ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'), ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'), ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'), ('et', 'Estonian'), ('eu', 'Basque'), ('fa', 'Persian'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ('fr', 'French'), ('fy', 'Frisian'), ('ga', 'Irish'), ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'), ('gl', 'Galician'), ('he', 'Hebrew'), ('hi', 'Hindi'), ('hr', 'Croatian'), ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'), ('hu', 'Hungarian'), ('ia', 'Interlingua'), ('id', 'Indonesian'), ('io', 'Ido'), ('is', 'Icelandic'), ('it', 'Italian'), ('ja', 'Japanese'), ('ka', 'Georgian'), ('kab', 'Kabyle'), ('kk', 'Kazakh'), ('km', 'Khmer'), ('kn', 'Kannada'), ('ko', 'Korean'), ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'), ('lt', 'Lithuanian'), ('lv', 'Latvian'), ('mk', 'Macedonian'), ('ml', 'Malayalam'), ('mn', 'Mongolian'), ('mr', 'Marathi'), ('my', 'Burmese'), ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'), ('ne', 'Nepali'), ('nl', 'Dutch'), ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'), ('os', 'Ossetic'), ('pa', 'Punjabi'), ('pl', 'Polish'), ('pt', 'Portuguese'), ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'), ('ro', 'Romanian'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('sk', 'Slovak'), ('sl', 'Slovenian'), ('sq', 'Albanian'), ('sr', 'Serbian'), ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'), ('sv', 'Swedish'), ('sw', 'Swahili'), ('ta', 'Tamil'), ('te', 'Telugu'), ('th', 'Thai'), ('tr', 'Turkish'), ('tt', 'Tatar'), ('udm', 'Udmurt'), ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('ur', 'Urdu'), ('vi', 'Vietnamese'), ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'), ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI = ['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
LOCALE_PATHS = []
LOGGING = {}
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None
MANAGERS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE = ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES = {}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING = 0
PASSWORD_HASHERS = '********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = '********************'
PREPEND_WWW = False
ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_server.urls'
SECRET_KEY = '********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
SECURE_SSL_HOST = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'django_server.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = []
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = None
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATES = [{'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS = []
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
USE_TZ = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = False
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_server.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'


You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your
Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will
display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a clean routine for this kind of situations, that I'll explain. first of all, `CurrentUserDefault` is not doing [something magical](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/90ed2c1ef7c652ce0a98075c422d25a632d62507/rest_framework/fields.py#L283), it is just returning the user of the `request` that we previously gave to the serializer (generic views pass the request to the serializer by calling `get_serializer`, since you are using generics you are doing fine).

but for our purpose, we'll write a new customized `CurrentUserDefault`, that it'll return the id of the user:

```
class CurrentUserDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.user_id = serializer_field.context['request'].user.id

    def __call__(self):
        return self.user_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode_to_repr('%s()' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

now we are just gonna use this CurrentUserDefault and fill the `owner_id` field of the `NoteSummarySerializer`, I suggest you use `serializers.HiddenField`, cause according to the drf doc:

> A field class that does not take a value based on user input, but instead takes its value from a default value or callable.
>
> This field will be present in validated_data but will not be used in the serializer output representation.

so it only gets its value from `default or callable`, so it's not `Changeable` by user input, and also it will not be used in the serializer output representation. seems great, right?

we just add this field to the serializer:

```
class NoteSummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_id = serializers.HiddenField(default=CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'title',
            'containerId',
            'created',
            'updated',
            'owner_id', ### dont forget to add it to the fields.
        )
```

then for final step, since we used `owner_id` fo filling the the owner, the name `owner` is available for other uses. in this case i think make it CharField and give `owner.username` (or anything you want) to its `source` and make its `readonly` True,
so our Serializer finnally gonna be like:

```
class NoteSummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_id = serializers.HiddenField(default=CurrentUserDefault())
    owner = serializers.CharField(source='owner.username', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'title',
            'containerId',
            'created',
            'updated',
            'owner_id',
            'owner'
        )
```

Comment: how do I use `owner` in my field validators? I guess I can't access by using self.owner...

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `context={'request': request}` to your serializer:

```py
serializer = NoteSummarySerializer(
    data=request.data, 
    context={"request": request}
)
```

With this the serializer instance will have the http request object in its context, and you can have access to the request user.