# Django Rest Framework - Django Nested serializer One to Many Relations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three models : **User(django auth model), Consumer, Tasks**.

> User model and Consumer has one to one relationship and Consumer and Task has one to many relationship.

My *model.py* goes like this:

```
class Consumer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    average_rating=models.FloatField(default=5.0)

class Tasks(models.Model):

    consumer=models.ForeignKey(Consumer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='consumer_obj')
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My *serializers.py* goes like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    category=serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        model=Tasks
        fields=['title','description']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password=serializers.CharField(max_length=10,write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=User 
        fields=['username','password','email']


class ConsumerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=UserSerializer()
    tasks=TaskSerializer(many=True,source='consumer_obj')
    class Meta:
        model=Consumer
        fields=['user','average_rating','tasks']
```

Now what I want to do is, Whenever I save a post a task, it should get save the task and associate itself to the current Consumer.

**What can be done.**

Now, whenever I call serializer.save() in my views I can pass a user instance as an argument something like this

```
 serializer.save(user=request.user)
```

And in my serializer create() function I can query the user and than query the consumer with the help of user to associate the task with that user.

I want to know if there is any better way to do this ? I'm new to DRF and having hard time learning it.

Answer (score 0):

you can Use the same approach that DRF uses for User, write a Custom object like `CurrentUserDefault` that returns the consumer correspondent to the currently authenticated user:

```
from rest_framework.compat import unicode_to_repr

class CurrentConsumerDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        user = serializer_field.context['request'].user
        self.consumer = user.consumer

    def __call__(self):
        return self.consumer

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode_to_repr('%s()' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

note: you should use the generic view or provide the request for the serializer yourself.

then in your `TaskSerializer`, add this field:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    consumer=serializers.HiddenField(default=CurrentConsumerDefault())

    class Meta:
        model=Tasks
        fields=['title','description', 'consumer']
```

read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942497/6177831) to a similar question for more information.

Comment: Does he need a `HiddenField`?

Comment: yeah, I guess, if he uses any other kind of field, the user can change the value. and it is a security bug.

Comment: Your **`CurrentConsumerDefault`**  is same as **`CurrentUserDefault`**----[Source Code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L281)

Comment: no, it returns the Consumer correspondent to the user. but i said before it is the same approach.