# Different logic for serializer on get and create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use one serializer in order to create comments and get list of them.

Here is my comment serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = UserBaseSerializer(source='author')
    replies = ShortCommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    reply_on = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Comment.objects.all(),
        write_only=True,
        allow_null=True,
        required=False
    )
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'object_id', 'creator', 'replies', 'reply_on',
                  'author')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'text': {'required': True},
            'object_id': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.update(
            {'content_type': self.context['content_type'],
             'object_id': self.context['pk']}
        )
        return Comment.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

My `Comment` model has field `author` which is FK to User model. On GET method I'm returning `creator` as NestedSerializer with `source='author'`. Also I got `author` field for write only purposes. I'm trying to figure out is it possible to use `author` field both for read and write.

Comment: It seems to me that author should be the currently logged-in user, you don't have to(actually, you should not) get its value from the front-end and you can assign it in your view or serializer, so you can leave the name author for the read-only use (UserBaseSerializer). take a look at my answer to another question, maybe it will give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942497/6177831

Comment: @changak Thank you, It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a [Writable Nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers). You're on the right track by having a defined `create`, but the linked documentation should hopefully give a good idea on how to implement this. You can avoid having to loop over your writable field since it's not a `many` relation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try override method get_serializer_class like this:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        return CommentCreateSerializer
    return CommentSerializer
```

In CommentCreateSerializer, you can write `author` field directly. And CommentSerializer with `source='author'` only for api get.

Hoop this help