# How to rename owner to owner_id in ModelSerializer using PrimaryKeyRelatedField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to rename my `owner` field to `owner_id` since it is not nested and will only contain the owner's id. I've made some attempts, but receive errors such as `{"owner":["This field is required."]}`.

Here is my serializers.py:

```
class UserJobApplicantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='job', queryset=Job.objects.all())
    owner_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='owner',
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = JobApplicant
        fields = [
            'id',
            'job_id',
            'owner_id',
            'timestamp',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['id',]
```

The view overrides the `perform_create` and injects the `owner_id` into the `validated_data`:

```
class UserJobApplicantAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = UserJobApplicantSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return JobApplicant.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.validated_data['owner_id'] = self.request.user.id
        return super(UserJobApplicantAPIView, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

Model (Job model holds the ManyToManyField with through='JobApplicant'):

```
class JobApplicant(models.Model):   
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                                                                      

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('owner', 'job')                                                                                               

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.job.display_name, self.owner.email)
```

What is the correct approach to doing this? Is it possible using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, or would I need to use another type of field (or custom)? I have it working for `job_id` but `job_id` is different since it's provided by the user.

I'm using DRF 3.8.2 with Django 1.11.15.

Comment: it is not a good idea to use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` for `owner_id` since the client can change its value, take a look at my answer, it might give you a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942497/6177831

Comment: Using `HiddenField` will break the `unique_together` constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the **`read_only=True,`** argument from **`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`** solve the ***main*** problem :)

It should be,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  # use the AUTH_USER_MODEL here

owner_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='owner', queryset=User.objects.all(), default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

**NOTE** : You don't want to override the **`perform_create()`** method to pass the user instance to serializer. The **`CurrentUserDefault()`** class will manage those things if you are properly logged-in

Comment: Removing `read_only=True` will cause it to require a queryset.

Comment: This solves it. I do have one concern--Since the `read_only=True` parameter is removed, couldn't the client send an `owner_id`?

Comment: If you set  `read_only=True`  to a field, it will **active** on **HTTP GET** request. While object creation(`HTTP POST`), the serializer assumes the `owner_id` is not present even if its there

Comment: Added `JobApplicant` model to my question.

Comment: That's good. Why do you want `owner_id` and `job_id` in your serialize ? (why did you add **`_id`** postfix to theose fields)?

Comment: I have two urlpatterns for `JobApplicant`. One is for a logged-in user (`example.com/api/v1/job-applications/`) and one is for the logged in Job poster (`example.com/api/v1/jobs/<job_pk>/applicants/`). When the clients are listing the `JobApplicant`, I didn't need nested objects. They will only get nested information when accessing the specific `JobApplicant` resource (ex: `example.com/api/v1/job-applications/<job_applicant_id>`). The main reason I have two urlpatterns is that a user cannot create a `JobApplicant` for the same `Job` more than once.