# Why is django-rest-frameworks request.data sometimes immutable?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my restful `CreateAPIView` I mutate my `request.data` dictionary.

Occasionally I receive an error not caught by my tests:

```
This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

For e.g. this:

```
class CreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ...
    queryset = ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['user'] = request.user.pk
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`request.data` seems to be a normal `dict` in my tests. Why is it sometimes a `QueryDict`? How should this be dealt with? Should request.data not be mutated in general? How should you use the `ModelSerializer` class, when you need to populate some fields yourself?

Comment: Can you add more info related to expected behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Why this *occasional* behavior?**

When we look into the [SC of Request](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f744da74d2878b480220ebaf9d8117ff9b79a947/rest_framework/request.py#L333) (as @Kenny Ackerman mentioned), it return a **`QueryDict`** object if you are passing a ***form media type*** (`'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` or `'multipart/form-data'`) data to the view class.
 This check being execute within the [**`is_form_media_type()`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f744da74d2878b480220ebaf9d8117ff9b79a947/rest_framework/request.py#L25) method of **`Request`** class.
If you are passing a `application/json` data to the view, the **`request.data`** will be a **`dict`** object.

> How to reproduce the behaviour?

It can be reproduce by using sending different `ContentType` data into view. (In POSTMAN tool, use `form-data` and `raw JSON` to get the behaviour)

> How to get ***current logged-in user*** in serializer?

**Method-1** pass extra argument to **`.save()`**  (as @Linovia mentioned) by overriding the **`perform_create()`** method

```
class CreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ...
    queryset = ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['user'] = request.user.pk
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**Method-2** Use [**`CurrentUserDefault()`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) class as below

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
    # your code
```

Comment: that or/and extend the serializer's save by adding extra keyword arguments (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save)

Comment: @Linovia Thanx for the tip. I've updated the answer. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

based on the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/request.py#L338) parser returns a querydict for data when the stream is empty(request.data calls `_load_data_and_files` method and `_load_data_and_files` calls `_parse` method).

and I think you can populate the fields using [HiddenField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield) or you can override the `create` or `update` method. for example

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'user')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        validated_data['populate_field'] = 'value'
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: I think overwriting the `create()` method instead of the `post()` method in combination with copying the dictionary might be a viable solution. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped, I meant to override the serializer `create` method, no the create method of the view.

Comment: just added an example.

Comment: This wouldn't work when `'value'` is somehow derived from `self.request` and `'populate_field'` is required in the serializer, as `is_valid` would fail

Comment: ok, I don't know your case but I think HiddenField is the best solution(this example might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942497/6177831). also, you can override the [field validate method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) and populate the value there

Answer (score 1):

When you have to modify a QueryDict object received from a request, it is a immutable object, instead use this line of code if you wanna add attributes:

```
myNewRequest = request.GET.copy()
myNewRequest.data['some_attr'] = float(something)
```

Comment: How does this work when e.g. subclassing `CreateAPIView` and overwriting `self.post`? In the end of that method, `return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)` is called. So I need to pass on the original request object. How do I deal with that?

Comment: If you want to return the original post with the data you added you can do it just return myNewRequest as itself, if you want to return the original just return request as itself because it's untouched. But what's the point the to add data i don't get it ?

Comment: e.g. saving a model with the request.user used as a model attribute

Comment: Based on your first question, you can append or update attributes as you want like a normal dictionary acting like a QueryDict, i don't really understand your last one but you can setup your model with a field based on your request.user, get/update the attributes in your copied QueryDict and add/update fields on your model.

Comment: my bad, I have updated the question. Seems like overwriting `self.create` instead of `self.post` allows me to use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this really depends on your selected parser specified in rest_framework's `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES` and the content type of your request:

JSONParser is implemented as follows:

```
return json.load(decoded_stream, parse_constant=parse_constant)
```

FormParser as follows:

```
return QueryDict(stream.read(), encoding=encoding)
```