# How can I reuse a DRF class-based views POST method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Now I want to reuse the post method of BundleList. Either I find out the absolute URL and use `requests.post(URL)` to send a request.

The 2nd way is to reuse by `return BundleList.as_view()(request)` in a view function. But I can't set `request.data = data`. Request data is immutable.

When I try to use

```
url = reverse_lazy(BundleList.as_view(), request=request)
print(f"{url = }")
```

It just gives me:

```
NoReverseMatch at /generateSampleBundle/
Reverse for 'my_app.views.BundleList' not found. 'my_app.views.BundleList' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

The BundleList is a class-based view with get and post method.

```
drfurlpatterns = [  # DRF URL endpoints
    path('bundles/', views.BundleList.as_view()),
]
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `name` for your view and use that name in `reverse_lazy()`

for ex:

```
drfurlpatterns = [  # DRF URL endpoints
    path('bundles/', views.BundleList.as_view()), name='bundle-list'
]
```

then

```
url = reverse_lazy('bundle-list', request=request)
```

see, [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/#reverse_lazy)

Also, to know why `request.data` is sometimes immutable [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367379/why-is-django-rest-frameworks-request-data-sometimes-immutable)