# Django Rest Framework, two different approach to POST request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i have question about two different approaches in DRF (Django Rest Framework) regarding POST request. So my question is if it is better to keep view and serializer simpler with **Approach 2** in beginning or is it more common to start with approach 1 because in this case it is more likely I would need .create() method in future?

**Approach 1:**

```
// view.py

class ExampleView1(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = CourseSerializer(data=data, context={"request": request}, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


// serializer .create() method

class ExampleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   def create(self, validated_data):
       user = self.context.get("request").user
       return Course.objects.create(**validated_data, owner=user)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
class ExampleView2(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        data["owner"] = request.user.pk
        serializer = CourseSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Typically one uses a `CreatAPIView` that does the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django follows the rapid development and DRY principles as described in the [home](https://www.djangoproject.com/) page.

With that in mind it means Django respects minimal codebase taking that into consideration the second approach is the way to go. Morever as @Willem Van Onsem suggested [CreatAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) will be more aligned to this as that will futher simplify the serializer logic.

**Edit:**

You can try this (not tested):

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

class ExampleView2(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
       data = self.request.data.copy()
       data['owner'] = self.request.user.pk
       kwargs['data'] = data
       return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also try changing `_mutable` attribute of your `request.data` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367379/why-is-django-rest-frameworks-request-data-sometimes-immutable/52368634) post.

**Note:** `request.data` is not always mutable it depends on the request.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Ahtisham. I am avoiding generics views as much as possible from the start (because I didn't understand OOP as much as I do know, and now I am kind of used of methods like get, post etc.).

So yes if I understand it correctly that means I could just replace last four lines with create method. But how exactly I can mutate request.data so I can pass user/owner instance to it? 

Something like this:
`
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data["owner"] = request.user
        return super().create(request)
`